# Mobile menu shows up briefly on desktop screen on loading

Tags: html, css

first of all, my design is responsive.

I use 2 different menus, one is for mobile sized screens and the other for desktop (>768px) sized screens.

If I visit my page with desktop, the mobile menu shows up briefly and disappears. It looks kinda bad if you visit the page.

my css code:

```
.menu_right{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 215px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .menu_right {
        display: none;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

any solutions to solve this issue?

best regards

Comment: Can you show us a demo or share link to live site?

Comment: You need this menu .menu_right to be visible or hidden on desktop, in another words is this the mobile menu or desktop menu ?

Answer (score 1):

You could set .menu_right to display none then use a media query to display it only for screen sizes that need it:

```
.menu_right{
 float:left;
 margin-left:10px;
 width:215px;
 display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .menu_right{
  display: block;
 }
}
```